# Regex to output different words in uppercase and lower case

Tags: javascript, regex, string, replace

I'm looking for a regex to output different words in uppercase and lower case.

Example string: DFBPokal

Current solution I have:

```
str.replace(/([a-z])([A-Z])/g, "$1 $2");
```

It does solve the problem when there's a str like 'HiAgain', but doesn't when it's 'HIAgain'.

How do I make it work within a condition that when a an uppercase word is at least >2 chars long, it identifies it as a word to be outputted as a var - either $1 or $2.

Comment: I guess you're looking for `{n}` or `{n,m}` or `+` quantifier. What is the expected output for the above two inputs

Comment: And what is the expected output for `HIAgain`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could replace

```
/([A-Z]+)(?=[A-Z][a-z])/g
```

With: `$1` in order to separate "HIAgain" into "HI Again".

```
'DFBPokal'.replace(/([A-Z]+)(?=[A-Z][a-z])/g, "$1 ");
// "DFB Pokal"
```

[**Example Here**](https://regex101.com/r/yU2aJ9/1)

It essentially selects uppercase letters until an uppercase letter followed by a lowercase letter.

---

If you want to catch both cases, you could replace:

```
/([A-Z]+)(?=[A-Z][a-z])|([a-z])(?=[A-Z])/g
```

With `$1$2` - [**Example Here**](https://regex101.com/r/cH3iB8/1)

Results:

```
"HIAgain" -> "HI Again"
"HiAgain" -> "Hi Again"
"DFBPokal" -> "DFB Pokal"
```

Comment: Thank you for a fast solution! I didn't respond earlier because I totally forgot to provide feedback after putting your solution to test.

Answer (score 0):

Simplest solution would be to use `/([a-z]|[A-Z]+)([A-Z])/g` instead of your regexp:

```
'HIAgain'.replace(/([a-z]|[A-Z]+)([A-Z])/g, "$1 $2"); -> 'HI Again'
'ABBRWord'.replace(/([a-z]|[A-Z]+)([A-Z])/g, "$1 $2"); -> 'ABBR Word'
```

The idea is to treat all but last capital letter as legitimate preceding word.